# Sencha touch 2 Datepicker field cancel button sets value

Tags: datepicker, sencha-touch-2

When you press the 'Cancel' button, the value appearing in the field is not updated, (that's ok) but fieldDate.getValue() gives the latest value, as if you did a 'Done'

```
    dateField = new Ext.field.DatePicker({
    style : style,
    id : data.ItemId,
    itemId : 'dateField',
    picker: {
        value: (new Date()),
        yearFrom : 1900
       }

   });
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Share ur controller code where u are facing the problem.

Comment: @AnandGupta actually I don't have any controller logic, just on click of Submit button on form, If I look at the value of 'data.ItemId' , then it's giving value, where user just selected 'Cancel' once DatePicker is opened .

Comment: This is strange issue Sujoy. If u can make working fiddle then anyone can reproduce the problem and more chances of getting solution. Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#home